# UML and iPhone developmenet

Tags: iphone

Do you use UML when you develop for iPhone? or its not the same when developing in a PC and developing in Mobile?

if you do ot youse UML, what we should use??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I require data modelling and am creating an iOS or Mac application, I will typically use core data. Core data supports a WYSIWYG editor for defining models (somewhat similar to UML) and I will typically do all my modelling directly in it. It is built into XCode and is accessible by opening a `.xcdatamodel` file.

If for whatever reason I choose not to use core data, I will typically use [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/). It is by far the best (UML) modelling application I have ever come across.

Answer (score 2):

UML is a [general purpose modeling language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) -- it can be used for any language, any platform, or even for something non-computer related -- e.g. suppose you're just trying to get your head around what's going on with a paper-based library booking system you have to operate. You could model that in UML to get a better understanding.